# What can I do if the UK Home Office has my passport and I have travel plans?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, passports, indian-citizens, uk-residents

I am an Indian passport holder, currently in the UK on a Tier 2 ICT visa. I have a valid US B1 visa.

Due to my job's role change, my passport and BRP went for an amendment to the UK Home Office but I have planned travel in one week. It looks like the decision on my visa amendment is taking more time, hence I am doubtful that I can travel to US as planned.

Will the Home Office will give any emergency document so I can travel to the US and come back to the UK? I have already booked my tickets and have been waiting for my passport for 5 weeks.

Answer (score 3):

The UK Home Office has no provision for [issuing a travel document](https://www.gov.uk/apply-home-office-travel-document) under such circumstances.  That only occurs or applies to those who cannot use or get a passport from their home country, e.g., refugees, asylum seekers.

While you can [request that your documents be returned](https://www.gov.uk/visa-documents-returned) to you, that may invalidate your request for further leave to remain.

As an Indian national, you could apply for an [emergency passport](https://portal1.passportindia.gov.in/AppOnlineProject/online/faqTatkaalPassports) through your own country. However, such circumstances may not qualify for issuance, particularly as it may cancel your current passport (and which has your US visa).

As inconvenient as it is, you may have to postpone or cancel your travel outside of the UK.

Comment: Applying for an emergency passport wouldn't help re-entry into the UK without a BRP also.